# mongodb tables disappereared somehow

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose, https, mean-stack

I am using mongodb 3.2.11 in Ubuntu Zesty 17.04 and I am connecting from Nodejs 4.6 to mongodb in HTTPS, the database server is bound to its own address (127.0.0.1) and I have created a user besides admin for read/write to the database.

Although, most of my tables were certainly dropped somehow, only users (empty) and sessions table were left.

I grepped my logs for "drop" with `grep -r "drop"` and got no results. Despite I am using very recent versions of the software and made some security measures they don't seem enough. At this time I don't need to recover the data, but I wanted to know what else should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "show collections" in the mongo shell in ubuntu and see if the collections are shown after doing "use dbnamehere".

Comment: After enabling authetication in mongod.conf and mongod --auth and restarting my server I can't connect to the mongodb with error 48. Here's the output > use webapplication switched to db webapplication > show collections 2017-09-21T17:20:51.871+0100 E QUERY [thread1] Error: listCollections failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on webapplication to execute command { listCollections: 1.0, filter: {} }", "code" : 13 } – staminna 7 mins ago

Comment: you are not adding corect credentials to login the mongoshell.

Comment: you need to do "db.createUser({user:"yourname", pwd:"password", roles:[{role:"root", db: "admin"}]})"